# Trello card covers

Tags: trello

I am able to upload an image to a card, but it won't show a thumbnail as the cover image of the card.  The image I uploaded is from my computer, not from Google Drive. We have seen this behavior when uploading from Google Drive, but not from computer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem today getting an image named "Priority 1.PNG" to show as a card cover. I suspected the space in the name to be problematic, but it turned out to be the uppercase 'PNG'. As soon as I renamed my file to "Priority 1.png" and uploaded it, the card immediately showed the thumbnail version and displayed it as the card cover.

I normally am a bit obsessive about my file names and rename to lowercase .png. But this morning I was lazy and left the default PNG generated by my screen grabber. Not sure if this will help your situation, but wanted to share my experience in case it does help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Both Google Drive & Dropbox attachments couldn't be used as a card cover when attached directly from those services. If you've linked your Dropbox folder to your desktop, you can use a file from Dropbox (given that it's now also on your computer).

Comment: What's the difference? Because it's linked locally?