# Card Covers not showing on iPhone Trello app

Tags: trello, trello-lists

I setup a Trello Board on my computer, added some lists and items, then put a cover on each (I searched for the image within Trello itself)

It looks fine on the web, but when I look at the board from the iPhone app, none of the images are showing. Is this a bug?

I found this question but it wasn't quite the same and didn't help as they uploaded their own images rather than searching directly through Trello:
[Trello card covers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30791/trello-card-covers)

Is this a bug? How can I fix it? Thanks.